# Extract datatype of list element

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently, I am working on determining the datatype of the list element.

Below example help you understand the problem:

```
l = ['jan-2019', 'xyz', '1234', '7.8']
```

current approach:

```
l = [type(i).__name__ for i in l]
```

but getting everything as a string as everything is in the string.

```
['string', 'string', 'string', 'string']
```

but the excepted format which I want to create is below:

```
['datetime', 'string', 'int', 'float']
```

Can anyone suggest me any other approach to achieve the expected format.

Comment: How `'1234'` and `'7.8'` could int and float?

Comment: In `l` the `'jan-2019'` is a string not a datetime and the same for `'1234'` and `'7.8'`.

Comment: I can't think of a way to cover all cases. You will have to actually implement something to parse the strings. If it were only ints and floats you might be able to use `eval`...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using regex module. Define fuctions for each type and check for the match.

```
import re

int_pattern = '^[0-9]+$'  
float_pattern = '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]*$'  
str_pattern = '^[a-zA-Z]+$'
date_pattern = '^[a-zA-Z]{3}(-)[1-9][0-9]{3}$'

def check_int(n):
     if re.search(int_pattern,n):
         return True
     else:
        return False

def check_float(n):
     if re.search(float_pattern,n):
         return True
     else:
        return False

def check_str(n):
     if re.search(str_pattern,n):
         return True
     else:
        return False

def check_date(n):
     if re.search(date_pattern,n):
         return True
     else:
        return False
```